# Bot Framework Cortana C# Adaptive Cards Action Buttons no longer working

Tags: c#, botframework, cortana, adaptive-cards

Has something changed with Cortana in the last few days?
I have buttons on an adaptive card which now do nothing. I have remote debugged and hit all breakpoints as expected but when tapping on a button nothing happens. It is as though the buttons are disabled somehow.
Everything works fine in the emulator.
My Bot code simply shows buttons in an adaptive card which then post their DataJson value which is received by the MessageReceivedAsync method.
I have been refining how this all works as I found that Cortana has a limit of 5 actions on one card. I did a bit of a work around in this and make each button appear on a card.
Therefore, I have been thinking that in my refining, I have done something to make these buttons no longer work.
However, I have now put my code back to how it was days ago which definitely did work in Cortana and it now does not work.
My question therefore is, has anything changed in the Cortana side to stop this?

Thanks!

Comment: I just thought that my phone is on the Insider Fast Ring and is now OS Build: 10.0.15254.527. Could this have updated, changed the Cortana app and caused this?

Comment: Things have changed (new OAuth fields and a need to regenerate a secret key), but I'm not sure I have enough information to help.  Is there an error?  What does Cortana's debug say?  What does the web app bot console say?

Comment: I create a sample using Adaptive Cards and do a test with Cortana channel, I can reproduce same issue: the **DataJson** value is not posted back to bot application when button(s) is clicked. It seems that Cortana does not full support Adaptive Cards, if possible, you can [create an issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/AdaptiveCards/issues) to report it.

Comment: I am trying to recreate a simple sample to confirm.

Comment: Hi @AlexanderPizzoferro, today I retest the bot with Cortana channel, same code using Adaptive Cards work as expected now, the DataJson value could be posted back to bot application if I click the button. Not sure if temporary issue with Cortana cause the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I modified the echodemo to put up a simple adaptive card and it worked as documented: "Thanks for Clicking! SomeType is SomeData".  (I am logging a ticket to update documentation to v1.0.3 of adaptive cards).

```
    public async Task ClickHandleAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> argument)
    {
        var message = await argument;
        try
        {
            string someValue = "unknown";
            if (message.Value != null)
            {
                // Got an Action Submit
                dynamic value = message.Value;
                string s = value.ToString();
                Trace.WriteLine(s);
                someValue = value.SomeType;
            }
            else
                Trace.TraceInformation("There is no value");

            //string data = message.ChannelData.ToString();
            //Trace.WriteLine(data);

            //Trace.TraceInformation("stringify message");
            //string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(message);
            //Trace.WriteLine(json);
            await context.PostAsync("Thanks for the click! SomeType is " + someValue);
            context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Trace.TraceInformation(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    public async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> argument)
    {
        var message = await argument;

        if (message.Text == "show card")
        {
            var response = context.MakeMessage();
            if (response.Attachments == null)
                response.Attachments = new List<Attachment>();

            AdaptiveCard card = new AdaptiveCard();

            card.Body.Add(new AdaptiveTextBlock()
            {
                Text = "This is a test",
                Weight = AdaptiveTextWeight.Bolder,
                Size = AdaptiveTextSize.Medium
            });

            card.Actions.Add(new AdaptiveSubmitAction()
            {
                Title = "Click Me",
                Id = "12345678",
                DataJson = "{ \"SomeType\": \"SomeData\" }"
            });

            Attachment attachment = new Attachment()
            {
                ContentType = AdaptiveCard.ContentType,
                Content = card,
                Name = "MyCard"
            };
            response.Attachments.Add(attachment);

            await context.PostAsync(response);
            context.Wait(ClickHandleAsync);
        }
```